# How are unitary matrices and unitary random matrices associated with physics or quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, definition, matrix-model

Please forgive my ignorance, my back ground is not physics. I am looking for  distance measure between two unitary matrix (for my work). So my starting point is where else unitary matrix is applicable? I found link associated with wave function and unitary matrix.  I can understand a little about wave function but I want to have a general idea where random unitary matrix comes into play in physics. Any comment link would be truly appreciated.

I am assuming certain wavefunction is unitary matrix. Hence, situation may be similar to: We have a instance of wavefunction, can we estimate probability to its previous wavefunction or close wavefunction? Another way to express as: We have a instance of wavefunction of a perturb system by noise can we associate probabilities to a perfect system from the instance? Do such question valid for wavefunction? Is there any principle exist to answer this question?

Question is such distance measure exist or not? Question is not broad.

Comment: That's very vague. In what context did you encounter those random unitary matrices and what reason do you have to believe it appears in quantum mechanics? Which *part* of quantum mechanics? Off the top of my head, random unitary matrices will for example feature prominently in Monte-Carlo approaches to lattice gauge theories with gauge groups $\mathrm{SU}(N)$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "random unitary matrix". Randomly distributed by what distributions in what parametrization? Random matrices certainly don't play any role in QM structurally. You would have to have a specific physical model that introduces an additional stochastic component.

Comment: As I understand it, random unitary/orthogonal/symptectic matrices appear in with random Hamiltonians, and so they're associated with disordered systems. Depending on the symmetry of the Hamiltonian you'll get a different kind of matrix and different correlations in the eigenvalues. I think that's the remarkable part of notice: even though the system is "random", you still get some weak correlations in behaviour, like localization, emerging out of protected symmetries.

Comment: I assumed 'random unitary matrix' has a very specific meaning in the literature. Let me check.

Comment: "Randomness" does have a very specific meaning in the literature. It's so "specific" that it fills a good part of the mathematics library...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows insufficient research effort: Googling "random matrix" quickly yields a wikipedia page which lists some applications in physics.

Answer (score 3):

In quantum mechanics (QM), normally we talk about the time evolution of some quantum state (QS), $|QS(t)\rangle$, of a particle. A QS is an entity that contains all the information we could possibly know about the particle and it can be treated as a vector in the Hilbert space. In the case of unitary evolution, mathematically, we have 
$$|QS(t_2)\rangle=U(t_2,t_1)|QS(t_1)\rangle$$
where $U$ is a unitary operator or unitary matrix from a vector point of view. We know that if a vector is acted on by a unitary operator, the length of the vector remains unchanged. The same thing happens in quantum mechanics, the length/norm of the QS vector in the Hilbert space will be preserved under unitary evolution. The corresponding physical meaning would be that the number of the particles are conserved, i.e. the particles are not suddenly destroyed or created.

And of course it might not be unitary in a more general case. Now let's come to the random unitary matrix you mentioned. Sometimes when we talk about particle motion in a disordered system (e.g. an optical fiber with randomly changing refractive index), then when light pass through, it's hard to figure out the details of the physical process inside the fiber, so in this kind of cases we can use a random unitary matrix to model the system and as a result we will not get something definite but everything becomes probabilistic.

Studying the properties of different types of random matrices belongs to the subject of random matrix theory, which has wide applications in modern physics, and people even think that it has deep connections to the Riemann hypothesis.

The classic text on this subject would be "random matrices" by Mehta.

Comment: normally we do not talk about the probability measure of the quantum states, instead we talk about observables, i.e quantities that can be measured experimentally. Again take the optical fiber as an example, we can calculate the probability (related to the eigenvalues of the random matrix) of the light passing through or being reflected back, which can be easily verified by experiment.

Comment: for your previous question, which you somehow deleted: you are right, that's how we calculate the probability density of the particles. There is something that I should have made clear. The aforementioned eigenvalues are the eigenvalues of some random transmission matrices, instead of the unitary evolution matrix and in fact they even have different dimensions.

Comment: The so-called transmission matrices are often used when dealing with scattering or transport problems as in the case of optical fiber or some disordered conductors. The transmission matrices does NOT tell you how the states evolve. It's more like a blackbox that gives you the output once you know the input.

Comment: In cases where there is no loss or gain of power, the transmission matrix is also unitary.

Comment: And for your current question: yes, it is possible to define some metric for the space of states, i.e. the Hilbert space, and there are many possible ways to define it, just like any Banach space of functions. Hilbert space is a special type of Banach space with an inner product defined. So here by distance, do you actually mean the overlap between two states? because that's what we care more about in QM.

Comment: what do you mean by distance measure based on AL?

Comment: sorry I really don't know what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I"m not sure that I understand what you mean by "random". Do you mean "arbitrary"?  That question aside, the unitary matrix is used in physics to effect similarity transformations of matrices in physics. 
$$A'=U^{\dagger} A U$$
where $U$ is the unitary transformation matrix and $U^{\dagger}$ is the Hermitian conjugate.  With this transformation, the eigenvalues of  and eigenvectors $A$ are preserved.   This is important in quantum mechanics because the eigenvalues represent the measurements of a system when operation $A$ occurs and the eigenvectors are analogues to the stationary state wave functions.

Unitary transformations are also used in classical mechanics to find principle axes of rotation and normal modes of vibration of systems of particles.

I'm sure that others will have additional applications of unitary matrices (and will graciously point out small nits that I mis-stated :)  ).